# Read contents of structure via RFC in SAP

Tags: saprfc

Is it possible to read contents of SAP structures via RFCs from the outside? I know that RFC_READ_TABLE can be used to read table data, but is there something similar for structures?

Or are structures only type definitions and don't contain any data?

Comment: Could you elaborate? A structure doesn't "contain data", unless you've got an instance of a structure (as a return parameter or table line type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, structures are only type definitions and don't contain any data.

That's why you have a RFC to read from tables (transparent tables, cluster tables, etc) but not from structures or table types.

Of course, a RFC can receive and return a structure as parameter, but again, that's only a structured type definition.